# How to get Narrator to read the text in a WPF Popup?

Tags: wpf, accessibility, narrator

I've got a WPF application which contains a button. When you press the button, a `Popup` opens. The `Popup` contains information about the meeting in question.

With Narrator turned on, the contents of the `Popup` are not being read.  How do I get Narrator to read the `Popup`'s contents?

Here's a sample of the `Popup`'s contents:

```
<Popup x:Class="ClassApp.UserInterface.Views.Windows.Settings.MeetingDetailsPopup"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:languages="clr-namespace:MyApp.UserInterface.CommonUI.Languages"
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:MyApp.Converters"
             xmlns:global="clr-namespace:"
             Height="375"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             MaxHeight="375"
             MaxWidth="500" 
             StaysOpen="True"
             Placement="MousePoint" 
             Width="500">
    <Border BorderBrush="{StaticResource GrayBrush}"
            Background="{StaticResource TabSelectedBackgroundBrush}"
            BorderThickness="1">
        <Grid Margin="10">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="25"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="35" />
                <RowDefinition Height="35"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="35"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="35"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"
                               MinHeight="100"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"
                               MinHeight="40"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid Grid.Column="0"
                  Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                  Grid.Row="0">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                           AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ClassName"
                           AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding ClassName}"
                           FontSize="18"
                           FontWeight="Bold"
                           x:Name="ClassName"
                           Style="{StaticResource ClassInformationTextBlockStyle}"
                           Text="{Binding ClassName}"
                           TextWrapping="Wrap"
                           VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <Button Grid.Column="1" 
                        AutomationProperties.Name="{x:Static languages:Resources.Accessibility_CloseWindow}"
                        AutomationProperties.AutomationId="CloseWindow"
                        Command="{Binding CloseMeetingInfoCommand}"
                        Content="X"
                        FontSize="16"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                        x:Name="CloseButton"
                        Style="{StaticResource ClassInformationCloseButtonStyle}"
                        VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            </Grid>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                       Grid.Row="1"
                       AutomationProperties.Name="{x:Static languages:Resources.Label_MeetingID}"
                       FontSize="14"
                       Foreground="{StaticResource GrayBrush}"
                       x:Name="MeetingIdLabel"
                       Style="{StaticResource ClassInformationTextBlockStyle}"
                       Text="{x:Static languages:Resources.Label_MeetingID}"
                       VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2"
                       Grid.Row="1"
                       AutomationProperties.AutomationId="MeetingId"
                       AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding MeetingID}"
                       AutomationProperties.LabeledBy="{Binding ElementName=MeetingIdLabel}"
                       FontSize="14"
                       Style="{StaticResource ClassInformationTextBlockStyle}"
                       Text="{Binding MeetingID}"
                       VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

                . . .
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Popup>
```

EDIT: The rest of the `Popup` consists of more `TextBlock`s and a couple of buttons for copying a link or all of the data into the clipboard. I didn't include it because I don't believe it matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set Popup.IsKeyboardFocused to true. The default value is false.

This will move the tab focus to the popup. Just remember that you'll need to move the focus back (preferably to the trigger that opens the popup) when the user closes it.

Comment: Thanks! So I set this in the code behind, right?

Comment: OK I tried this just now and I found that `Popup.IsKeyboardFocused` does not have a setter. However, I called `Focus()` on the `Popup` and that did it. I added a private field to the backend of the popup to remember which `IInputElement` had focus before the `Popup`. This is all working great. The only problem is that the screen reader isn't reading the text in the dialog. It's all in `TextBlock` controls. I'm going to try using read only `TextBoxes` to get the text to be read.

Comment: I fixed the problem with the `TextBlock` controls not being read by Narrator by changing them into `Label` controls and creating a `Style` for `Label` controls that uses a `TextBlock` to display the contents.